# Automapper to Map two List Classes of different structure and also Memberwise explicit Mapping

Tags: asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, .net-core, automapper

I have 4 classes namely ClassA, ClassADto,  ClassAA(inner class to ClassA) and the final Result class.

```
ClassAA
{
public int HouseNumber{get;set;}
public string StreetName{get;set;}
public string State{get;set;}
}

ClassA
{
public int Age{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public ClassAA AObj[get;set;}
}

ClassADto
{

 public int Age{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}

}

class Result
{
public string StreetName{get;set;}
public int TotalCount{get;set;}
public int TodaysDate{get;set;}
public List<ClassADto> AObjectsList{get;set;}
}
```

Now my aim is map the '*Result*' class with the List of *ClassA* object to fill it the property 'AObjectsList'  as below:
    **Result data= map mapper.map>(obj);**

Also at the same time in automapper i want to use custom function either using '*Resolve*' or '*AfterMap*' to set properties like '*TodaysDate*' to current datetime of system and property 'TotalCount' by counting the number of data.

I tried in many ways using '*CreateMap*' and also used '*ForMembers*' as from '*classAA*' we only need the '*StreetName*' but it didn't work. Need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

One time typing approach ;)

```c
public static Result ToResult(this List<ClassA> users)
{
   return new Result
   {
       TotalCount = users.Count,
       TodaysDate = DateTime.Today,
       AObjectsList = users
           .Select(user => new ClassADto
           {
               Name = user.Name,
               Age = user.Age
           })
           .ToList()
   };
}

// Usage
var users = new List<ClassA> { new ClassA(), new ClassA() };

var result = users.ToResult();
```

Comment: Fabio with linq and extension method it is achievable but I need to do it with Automapper. Is it possible.